# Displaying database contents on a html webpage

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to display all of the records from a database in phpMyAdmin. This database is located on my computer which is currently a server because of the Uniform Server software installed on it recently. I am new to building php and html code. I used the last compete documenet code from this link http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/display_table_data.htm and this is the output on my web page.

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>

<TITLE> LOG INFORMATION FOR ALL customers </TITLE>

</HEAD>


<BODY>

<H1> LOG INFORMATION FOR ENTIRE DATABASE </H1>

<?php


$database="mobile_app_tracking_log";

mysql_connect(localhost);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query="SELECT * FROM tablename";
$result=mysql_query($query);



mysql_close();
?>

<table border="2" cellspacing="7" cellpadding="7">
<tr>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Index</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Identification Number</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Date</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Time</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Application</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Usage</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Latitude</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Longitude</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Address</font></th>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {


$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"Index");
$f2-name=mysql_result($result,$i,"Identification Number");
$f3-name=mysql_result($result,$i,"Date");
$f4-name=mysql_result($result,$i,"Time");
$f5-name=mysql_result($result,$i,"Application");
$f6-name=mysql_result($result,$i,"Usage");
$f7-name=mysql_result($result,$i,"Latitude");
$f8-name=mysql_result($result,$i,"Longitude");
$f9-name=mysql_result($result,$i,"Address");
?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f6; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f7; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f8; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f9; ?></font></td>
</tr>


<?php

$i++;
}

?>
```

Can somebody please tell me why the records from the database aren't showing? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are saving the variable `$f2-name` however you are echo'ing `$f2`, same with `$f3`, `$f4` etc.

If you want to keep your naming schema, you have do do:

```
echo $f2-name;
echo $f3-name;
// etc
```

Comment: Thanks, but i thought I did that for each all the rows like this one: <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td> Isn't the code segment <?php echo $f1; ?> supposed to print the value. I don't quite get it.

Comment: Edited post as per your changes.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I did what you suggested, but I'm still getting blank table. Any more suggestions? Is something wrong with how I tried to connected to the database on Uniform web server?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code compare to the links you've provided. Your missing the $num variable initialization

This one:
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

So I guess your loop will not iterate, adding this may resolve your problem. Better look more on the code you referred some might be missing on your code.

Comment: Thanks Ace, I appreciate it. I'll try it out and tell you how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

check this code.. This may help you..

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> LOG INFORMATION FOR ALL customers </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1> LOG INFORMATION FOR ENTIRE DATABASE </H1>

<?php
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$database="test";

mysql_connect(localhost,$user, $password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
echo $query = "SELECT * FROM customer";
$result = mysql_query($query);

mysql_close();
?>

<table border="2" cellspacing="7" cellpadding="7">
<tr>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Index</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Customer Name</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Sex</font></th>
</tr>

<?php

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $row[id]; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $row[customer_name]; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $row[sex]; ?></font></td>
</tr>


<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this code and I found it was necessary to put quotes around `localhost` in the `mysql_connect` line

```
mysql_connect('localhost',$user, $password);
```

as well as the `$row` result lines to avoid getting `"Notice: Use of undefined constant" errors.`

```
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></font></td>
```